# UPDATE en múltiples tablas con JOIN

Tags: php, sql, join

Lo que pasa es que quiero hacer un `UPDATE` de 4 tablas, para ello solo me he metido a hacer un `UPDATE` de dos tablas (para uso práctico).

Las tablas son:

```
*contratos
- id_contratos
- fecha_de_contrato
- cliente_id <-- FK
- plan_id  <-- FK

*clientes
- id_cliente
- nombre
- tel1

*planes_mb
- id_plan_mb
- mbps
```

Hasta donde de probado, el Query "podría" ser el siguiente:

```
UPDATE contratos
JOIN clientes 
ON contratos.id_contratos = clientes.id_cliente
SET `nombre` = 'AquiAlgunNombre' 
WHERE contratos.id_contratos
```

Para un panorama mayor, hago ya unos JOIN que me ayudan a VISUALIZAR (get)
las 4 tablas (que requiero)  en una sola con el siguiente método:

```
public function getClientes(){ //Muestra 4 tablas en 1
        $this->db->select("con.*, plan.*, dom.*, cli.*");
        $this->db->from("contratos con");
        $this->db->join("planes_mb plan", "con.plan_id = plan.id_plan_mb");
        $this->db->join("domicilios_instalaciones dom", "con.domicilio_instalacion_id = dom.id_domicilio_instalacion");
        $this->db->join("clientes cli", "con.cliente_id = cli.id_cliente");
        $this->db->where("con.borrado","1");
        $resultados = $this->db->get();
        return $resultados->result();
    }
```

Y este otro método que actualiza SOLO UNA tabla:

```
public function update($id_plan_mb,$data){
        $this->db->where("id_plan_mb",$id_plan_mb); 
        return $this->db->update("planes_mb", $data);
    }
```

Basándome en esos códigos hice lo siguiente, que debería actualizar tan solo 2 tablas (por ahora):

```
public function update($id_contratos_d, $data){
        $this->db->join("clientes", "contratos.id_contratos_d = clientes.id_cliente");
        $this->db->where("id_contratos_d", "$id_contratos_d");
        return $this->db->update("contratos", $data);
    }
```

Pero no me sale nada en lo absoluto, me arroja "Unknown column 'nombre' in 'field list'  ".

Y si no es mucho pedir, un ejemplo ya metiendo un el update de 3 tablas al menos...

¡Gracias!

Comment: Tu problema es que estás diciendo que quieres actualizar el campo `nombre` de la tabla `clientes` y sin embargo en tu SQL pones `UPDATE contratos` que significa que quieres actualizar tu tabla contratos, donde no existe el campo `nombre`. Recuerda que siempre te viene bien marcar los nombres de tablas con la referencia completa: `clientes.nombre`. De esa forma el mensaje de error te ayudará más a entender qué ocurre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres modificar un campo de la tabla `clientes` entonces es esta tabla la que debes indicar en el campo `WHERE` y no la tabla `contratos` que no tiene ningún campo que se llame `nombre`:

```
UPDATE clientes cl
  JOIN contratos co
    ON co.id_contratos = cl.id_cliente
  JOIN planes_mb pl
    ON co.plan_id = pl.id_plan_mb
SET cl.nombre = 'AquiAlgunNombre'
WHERE co.id_contratos = XXX
```

En cuanto a la relación con una tercera tabla, ten en cuenta que has de poner los `JOIN` primero en los que obtienes los datos para la relación con las siguientes tablas. En este caso la prioridad es sacar los datos asociados de la tabla `contratos` que es en la que están las relaciones con el resto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, tenías toda la razón. Pero, esto funciona bien para dos tablas, y mi pregunta ahora es, como sería si tratara de actualizar a cuatro (incluyendo actualizar la misma tabla "clientes"??  No se si me pudieras apoyar con eso, no importa que inventes algo demasiado ficticio... Y perdona, pero créeme: soy nood :(

Comment: Sería ir anidando más `JOIN/ON`. Si agregas otra tabla adicional en tu pregunta podré ponerte un ejemplo con una tabla más.

Comment: Listo, y de verdad gracias por echarme una mano con esto

Comment: Ya he hecho la edición. Ten en cuenta que has de poner los `JOIN` primero en los que obtienes los datos para la relación con las siguientes tablas. En este caso la prioridad es sacar los datos asociados de la tabla `contratos` que es en la que están las relaciones con el resto de tablas.

Comment: Mil gracias, valla que andaba perdido, pero tu aporte me ah ayudado de mucho  :D

Comment: En SQL, la consulta sale sin problemas. Pero al pasarlo en ya en práctica php (con mi noción y pruebas pasadas) esto no me funciona, también me pone a cuestionar cuando haga un update en la tabla "contratos", como sería? Aquí es como lo hice hasta el momento.       public function update($id_cliente, $data){
        $this->db->join("contratos", "contratos.id_contratos = clientes.id_cliente");     $this->db->join("planes_mb", "contratos.plan_id = planes_mb.id_plan_mb");
        $this->db->where("cliente.id_cliente", "$id_cliente");
        return $this->db->update("cliente", $data);
    }

Comment: Para actualizar `contratos` debes usar `UPDATE contratos`. Para una pregunta acerca de cómo implementar esta consulta SQL en un framework específico deberías crear una nueva pregunta indicando qué framework usas. Los comentarios no son buen lugar para pegar código fuente, queda ininteligible.